# MySQL Return latest and longest streak of rows with certain conditions

Tags: mysql

Please have a look at this fiddle.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71CxYHKkzwmXJnovzpFheV/7

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things:

1. How do I get the length and date of the LATEST STREAK OF CORRECT GUESSES (meaning Result = Guess) without any skipped dates? In this case, it would be 4, starting from 2021-01-05 to 2021-01-08. (Although 2021-01-03 is correct, because there was no guess on 2021-01-04, it should not be included).
2. How do I get the length and date of the LONGEST STREAK OF CORRECT GUESSES OF ALL TIME? Again meaning Result = Guess, but can be anywhere in the table. Let's say it's 10 from 3 months ago.

To further complicate things, guesses can be made by multiple users AND there will be multiple results (for different game categories for example) on the same day. So the table above is for one user and one game category. I *think* I can handle this if I can get some guidance on the goals up above.

This is beyond my understanding. Any and all help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've changed the table to show that the date is not always sequential. Also, I was informed that I should be using MySQL 8.0 for this task as using variables is not good practice for this problem.

Edit: Using the window functions, starting to get somewhere:

Please check the fiddle. It's pretty close to what I'm trying to get to, but the '4' in the total column should be a 1. In other words, the "sum" should restart. Not sure how to achieve this, because it's clear that the window function will group based on the conditions, breaking the order and thus the streak.

**Updated:** I've updated the fiddle per @The Impaler's request. The table here is more representative to what I'm actually working with (still not exact, but much closer).

Since this new fiddle is more representative, I'll also explain my final goal. I'd also like to get the streak for each game_type. The way I've been comparing game_type result on a given day to "community" (basically all the users) guess is by summing all the 0's and 1's for each game_type on that date from all the users and then using whichever greater as the 'guess'. This way, I can get how the "community" is doing as a whole. This works for individual dates, but to do a streak, I'm not sure.

**Update 2**
So this is as far as I've got:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71CxYHKkzwmXJnovzpFheV/11

I tried to do a nested window function but that's not allowed. I have the proper groupings and column for when guess = result. Now I need help figuring out the streak within the groups.

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.x you should be able to do this using window functions.

Comment: I've actually been at this for the past couple of hours. I've tried group by, order by, and limits to no avail. I have searched trying to see if it was possible to create a conditional limit (like "LIMIT WHEN result != guess), which is not allowed. I didn't post any of my attempts because nothing got me remotely close.

I'm running MySQL 5.x but I'll look into 8.x now.

Comment: You need to post your best attempt. We're not going to write it for you, but we'll help you understand what you were doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Date certainly appears to be always sequential

Comment: The actual table does not have sequential dates. I just created a simple example to get at the heart of my challenge. The actual table/db structure is actually a bit more complex, but this example captures what I'm trying to achieve. I 'believe' I can handle the other stuff.

Comment: @Strawberry I left a comment on one of your answers to a similar question to this. I'm hoping you can help out.

Comment: If dates aren't sequential, then I suggest to revise your sample data set, and desired result, accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the table and added a bit more information about the criteria. What functions in MySQL 8 should I be looking at to achieve this?

Comment: `Let's say it's 10 from 3 months ago.`  I don't see how this fits with the data set. Why not follow Barmar's advice above?

Comment: Took your advice and have started playing with the window functions. I've added in my edits. The issue now is, how do I constrain the rows to not get reordered?

Comment: I've updated the question with a fiddle. I'm getting close! Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: As of right now, I can't think of anything that might work besides the use of variables. Why are variables considered bad practice?

Comment: Is this possible or will I have to handle it server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it took a while, but thanks to @The Impaler providing me the basis and the link below, I was able to solve the problem.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/efficient-solutions-to-gaps-and-islands-challenges/

Here is the full solution:

```
with GAME_LOG as (
  select 
    *,
    guess = result as correct,
    lag(case when (guess = result) then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by user_id, game_type) as previous_game_result,
    lead(case when (guess = result) then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by user_id, game_type) as next_game_result,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id, game_type order by dayt DESC) as ilocation
  from mytable
),
  
CTE_ISLAND_START as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id, game_type order by dayt DESC) as inumber,
    dayt as island_start_time,
    ilocation as island_start_location
  from GAME_LOG
  where correct = 1 AND
    (previous_game_result <> 1 OR previous_game_result is null)
),

CTE_ISLAND_END as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by user_id, game_type order by dayt DESC) as inumber,
    dayt as island_end_time,
    ilocation as island_end_location
  from GAME_LOG
  where correct = 1 AND
    (next_game_result <> 1 OR next_game_result is null)
)

select
  CTE_ISLAND_START.user_id,
  CTE_ISLAND_START.game_type,
  CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_time as streak_end,
  CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_time as streak_start,
  cast(CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_location as signed) - 
   cast(CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_location as signed) + 1 as streak
from CTE_ISLAND_START
inner join CTE_ISLAND_END
on CTE_ISLAND_START.inumber = CTE_ISLAND_END.inumber AND
  CTE_ISLAND_START.user_id = CTE_ISLAND_END.user_id AND
  CTE_ISLAND_START.game_type = CTE_ISLAND_END.game_type
```

This will give all the streaks for each user_id, each game_type, as well as the start and end dates of the streak.

You can simply add a `WHERE` clause to filter by game_type and user_id.

Here's the fiddle with slightly updated dataset.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71CxYHKkzwmXJnovzpFheV/19)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical "Gaps & Islands" problem. Once you assemble the islands the query becomes easy.

For example, for a single user, as stated in the fiddle you can get the LONGEST STREAK by doing:

```
with 
i as (
  select
    min(dayt) as starting_day,
    max(dayt) as ending_day,
    count(*) as streak_length
  from (
    select *, sum(beach) over(order by dayt) as island
    from (
      select *,
        guess = result as inland,
        case when (guess = result) <> (
          lag(guess) over(order by dayt) = lag(result) over(order by dayt))
          then 1 else 0 end as beach
      from mytable
    ) x
    where inland = 1
  ) y
  group by island
)
select *
from i
order by streak_length desc
limit 1;
```

Result:

```
starting_day  ending_day  streak_length 
------------- ----------- ------------- 
2021-01-06    2021-01-08  3
```

To get the LATEST STREAK you just need to change the `ORDER BY` clause at the end as shown below:

```
with 
i as (
  select
    min(dayt) as starting_day,
    max(dayt) as ending_day,
    count(*) as streak_length
  from (
    select *, sum(beach) over(order by dayt) as island
    from (
      select *,
        guess = result as inland,
        case when (guess = result) <> (
          lag(guess) over(order by dayt) = lag(result) over(order by dayt))
          then 1 else 0 end as beach
      from mytable
    ) x
    where inland = 1
  ) y
  group by island
)
select *
from i
order by ending_day desc
limit 1;
```

Result (same result as before):

```
starting_day  ending_day  streak_length 
------------- ----------- ------------- 
2021-01-06    2021-01-08  3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/71CxYHKkzwmXJnovzpFheV/4).

**Note**: You can remove the `LIMIT` clause at the end to see all the islands, not just the selected one.

For multi-users it's just a matter of modifying the windows (adding partitioning) and the rest of the query remains the same. If you provide a fiddle for multi-users I can add the solution as well.

Comment: First, let me thank you for taking the time to answer this question. This is marvelous! I did not know this was a known problem and will do some research on "gaps and islands". I have not fully parsed through your answer to understand it all yet, but I'm working on it. I have updated the fiddle per your request and created a table that's more representative of what I'm dealing with. I've also updated my question to add in my final goal (which wasn't possible with the original table). I'm going to take what you've done so far to get as far as I can. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: Updated the original again with my latest attempts. Definitely made progress thanks to you but still stuck. I'm getting very tempted to use variables for this...

Comment: I've figured it out! Your answer gave me the foundation so I've rewarded you the bounty. I'll post the full answer shortly.

Comment: @MikelG Glad you figured out the `PARTITION BY` clause that was needed.